# Problems with decorator with arguments to wrap class method

Tags: python, decorator, class-method, python-decorators

I am trying to write a decorator with arguments that wraps methods for a particular class.  I've tried both a function and a class decorator and run into different errors.  Playing around with arguments for the signatures hasn't helped.

**Example usage**

```
class X(object):
    def __init__():
        self.a = True
        self.b = ""

    @my_deco([])
    def xfunc(self, x, y):
        do stuff...

foo = X()
foo.xfunc()
```

**Function decorator:**

```
def my_deco(param1):
    def wrapped(func):
        def wrapped_f(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                self.a = True
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                self.b = str(e)
                self.a = False
                return param1
        return wrapped_f
    return wrapped
```

Gives this error: TypeError: wrapped() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

**Class decorator:**

```
class my_deco(object):

    def __init__(self, param1=False):
        self.param1 = param1

    def __call__(self, f):

        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped_f(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                self.a = True
                return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                self.b = str(e)
                self.a = False
                return self.param1
        return wrapped_f
    #
    #def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
    #    """Support instance methods."""
    #    import functools
    #    return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)
```

Gives this error: TypeError: **call**() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Any clues how to get this to work?

Comment: Please show how you're using the decorated method.  And provide the complete traceback.

Comment: Also, note that at the very least your decorated method still has to accept a `self` argument.

Comment: I just updated the example, realized I left the arguments for the method.  The stack trace just points to the function call, nothing deeper.

Comment: Your code also refers to an undefined variable `exc_return` and an undefined attributed `self.exc_return`.  Please post the actual code you are running.

Comment: Can you post the exception traceback?

Comment: Then you need to make new code, a simple example showing your problem.  It needs to be actual runnable code that you have actually run to verify that it shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In trying to create runnable code to post as an example, I came across my error.  Probably got mixed up at some point in writing the wrapper and trying to get it to work, I overlooked a simple mistake.

Below is the working example.  The mistake I made, was I didn't pass a parameter to the decorator for the method I was testing, thus causing the exception.  This explains the problem since the decorator was expecting a parameter.

```
def my_deco(param1):
    def wrapped(func):
        def wrapped_f(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                self.a = True
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                self.b = str(e)
                self.a = False
                return param1
        return wrapped_f
    return wrapped

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2
        self.a = False
        self.b = ""

    @my_deco([])
    def xfunc(self, x, y):
        return x + y

def ClassFactory(attr1, attr2, base=Base):
    class NewClass(Base):
        def __init__(self):
            super(NewClass, self).__init__(attr1, attr2)

    return NewClass

ChildClass = ClassFactory("foo", "bar")
child = ChildClass()

print child.xfunc(1, 2) # no exception
print child.xfunc('x', 2) # throws exception
```